# WPF Image background sprites image

Tags: wpf

In WPF image control,

```
< Image Source="icon.png" />
```

Now I want to change icon, without using the other image as icon1.png,
Is there a way to set background position like in css? 
So that i can keep multiple icon images in icon.png and show the one required rather then having multiple images as icon1.png, icon2.png.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="<some path>" SourceRect="X,Y,W,H" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Just a small example. For further details you can see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap.aspx).